# how to make Text.rich content as much space?

Tags: flutter, dart, textspan

I'm trying to display a page of Quran in one screen by using Text.rich but some text can't appear.How to make Text.rich content  as much space?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMdhl.png)

I'm trying to display a page of Quran in one screen by using Text.rich but some text can't appear.How to make Text.rich content  as much space?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to wrap your Text.rich widget with ***Expanded***

```
Expanded(
  child: Text.rich(
    // your text goes here
  ),
),
```

Comment: already ,i did this but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll your page to see the whole content, try to wrap the content of your page in a `SingleChildScrollView`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Text.rich(
    // ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: i don't want that, i want to display all data without scroll

Comment: Do you want smaller font-size?